# Remove Microsoft Teams from Ubuntu

Tags: software-uninstall, microsoft-teams

Running Ubuntu 20.04. I installed Ms Teams a year ago for work and it worked fine. I have both MS Teams "insiders" and "preview" versions.

A few weeks ago, they stopped working. When I try to access meetings, I am told to log in (which isn't needed as I did the same with my android phone and it wasn't required) or most of the time, the Teams software just won't load.

Other answers given here say "sudo apt remove teams" as the solution, but when I try this it says that teams is not installed? However in my software menu, both Teams insiders and Teams Preview appear as selectable, even though they don't load.

So what should I do to remove Teams from my computer completely?

I just want to get rid of this program and try to reinstall it as I need this for work.

Edit:

```
apt list teams
Listing... Done
teams/stable 1.4.00.26453 amd64
N: There are 9 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

$ snap list teams

```
Name   Version       Rev  Tracking       Publisher  Notes
teams  1.4.00.26453  6    latest/stable  msteams✓   -
```

Edit: Solved now. It was a snap package so needed a snap command to remove, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hello. You need to know how Teams was installed. Was it  an apt install, a flatpak a snap or what?

Comment: Have you checked that the files referenced by your software menu entry are actually present?

Comment: Try running `apt search teams` to locate any packages when Microsoft Teams was installed. If it wasn't installed by apt, it may not work. @user68186 Sorry, I posted this right after you did. That was unintentional

Comment: @user68186 I didn't expect that. Do you even have 
Microsoft Teams installed?

Comment: @user68186  Hi. I've edited in the responses from the commands you said.

Comment: Please don't put "solved" and the solution in the body of the question. The green check mark next to the correct answer is sufficient. Of course you are free to answer your own question and mark that as the correct one if you feel my answer is inadequate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have the snap versions of Microsoft Teams installed.

However, Teams can be also be installed using two different methods, the PPA and the snap store. The ways to uninstall either or both are listed below:

## Remove Teams installed from the Snap Store

Open a terminal and enter the command:

```
sudo snap remove teams
```

Snaps automatically saves a snapshot of the data used by the app. To remove the saved data as well as the app use the command:

```
sudo snap remove --purge teams
```

If you have `teams-insiders` installed via snap, you can uninstall it similarly.

## Remove Teams installed from the PPA

Open a terminal and enter the command:

```
sudo apt remove teams
```

You will be asked for your password. When you type the password the cursor will not move there will be no ***** of any kind. This is normal. Enter the password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This command will uninstall the software but keep the configuration files, in case you want to install and use it later.

Installing Teams this way adds Microsoft's Teams PPA repository in the list of sources.

If you want to remove the configuration files along with the app as well as the PPA, use these two commands:

```
sudo apt remove --purge teams
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list
```

The `-i` option will ask you if you are sure before deleting the PPA.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I also removed Teams Insiders by making the command:  sudo snap remove teams-insiders

Comment: also check: `sudo apt autoclean` if not listed